# How do i sync tags on laravel

Tags: laravel, tags

`insertData` Controller

```
    public function insertArticle(Request $request)
            {
                $article = new Article();
                $article->title = $request['title'];
                $article->content = $request['content'];

                //code to sync tags for this article

                $article->save()
                return redirect()->back();
           }
```

Tags are located in another table called `tags` containing `id` and `name`. I am connecting `tags` table to `articles` table by using pivot table `article_tag` which contains `article_id` and `tag_id` entries, and i have set up the relations as well as the foreign keys in the pivot table. What i am wishing to do is synchronize `tags`  for a certain `article` when i need to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method for that:

```
public function insertArticle(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();
    $article->title = $request['title'];
    $article->content = $request['content'];
    $article->save();

    $article->tags()->sync($tagsIdsArray);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

> The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table

Comment: But where do i define $tagsIdsArray

Comment: @ArditMata well, if you want to sync tags, you have to have a list of tags somewhere. If have the list in the form, just parse it in a controller method.